# How to show view controller with full screen in SwiftUI with Builder Module (UIKit)?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, viper-architecture

I am new at iOS development and i have some trouble...

I use SwiftUI with architecture - VIPER/B. It is my first step in ios dev with this stack.

I take base project from [here](https://theswiftdev.com/how-to-build-swiftui-apps-using-viper/)

So I have func that build my module and it return me `ViewController`:

```
final class HomeModule: ModuleInterface {
    typealias View = HomeView
    typealias Presenter = HomePresenter
    typealias Router = HomeRouter
    typealias Interactor = HomeInteractor

    func build() -> UIViewController {
        let presenter = Presenter()
        let interactor = Interactor()
        let router = Router()

        let viewModel = HomeViewModel()
        let view = View(presenter: presenter, viewModel: viewModel)
            .environmentObject(AppEnvironment())
        presenter.viewModel = viewModel

        self.assemble(presenter: presenter, router: router, interactor: interactor)

        let viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
        router.viewController = viewController
        return viewController
    }
}
```

After, i call this func in my `Router`:

```
final class LoginRouter : LoginRouterProtocol {
    
    weak var presenter : LoginPresenter!
    
    weak var viewController: UIViewController!
    
    func presentHomeScreen() {
        
        viewController.present(HomeModule().build(), animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
}
```

I didn’t think of any other way to call the builder module except as `viewController.present`, and besides, `weak var viewController: UIViewController!` was already announced in the original template, which prompted `viewController.present`

And as result when I call this func in my `View`, i get my `ViewController` modally, but i can't get full screen presentation.

Func in my `Presenter`:

```
var router : LoginRouter!

func login() {
    router.presentHomeScreen()
}
```

Func in my `View`:

```
Button(action: {   
  self.login()
}) {
  Text("Log in")
}

func login() {
    presenter.login()
}
```

How can I present this in full screen mode? And I want to show the segue like in default `NavigationController`: when new `ViewController` appear from left to right. Also, I try to use `NavigationLink`, but parameter destination must get type `View`, not `ViewController`... And it give me an error:

> Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

Comment: `viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen` can you add this in presentHomeScreen function before present

Comment: @MShah i tried this, but this is useless